# SpringBoot- convert SYS_REF_CURSOR into java List is not working

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
  <groupId>com.xx.rt.report</groupId>
  <artifactId>rt-report-service</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>rt-report-service</name>
  <description>Data check report</description>
  <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.6</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.virtuald</groupId>
            <artifactId>curvesapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.06</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**OpenFindingRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface OpenFindingRepository extends CrudRepository<OpenFindingDTO, Serializable> {
    @Procedure(name="getOpenFindings")
    List<OpenFindingDTO> getOpenFindings(@Param("INPUT_DATE") String dataDate);
}
```

**OpenFindingDTO.java**

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "getOpenFindings",
    procedureName = "OPEN_CODE_FINDINGS",
    resultClasses = OpenFindingDTO.class,
    parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "INPUT_DATE", type = String.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "C_OUTPUT", type = void.class)
    })})
@Entity
public class OpenFindingDTO {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name=Constants.FINDING_ID_PK)
    private String findingID;
    @Column(name=Constants.REVIEW_ID_PK)
    private String reviewID;
    @Column(name=Constants.REVIEW_ID_STR)
    private String reviewIDStr;
    public String getFindingID() {
        return findingID;
    }
    public void setFindingID(String findingID) {
        this.findingID = findingID;
    }
    public String getReviewID() {
        return reviewID;
    }
    public void setReviewID(String reviewID) {
        this.reviewID = reviewID;
    }
    public String getReviewIDStr() {
        return reviewIDStr;
    }
    public void setReviewIDStr(String reviewIDStr) {
        this.reviewIDStr = reviewIDStr;
    }
}
```

**BBMReportServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class BBMReportServiceImpl implements BBMReportService {
    @Autowired
    ToolUtility toolUtil;
    @Autowired
    ALMReportDAO almReportDAO;
    @Autowired
    OpenFindingRepository openFindingRepository;
    public Object createFile() {
        Object obj=null;
        try {
            XSSFWorkbook workBook = toolUtil.createFile();
            List<OpenFindingDTO> openFindingList = openFindingRepository.getOpenFindings(Constants.INPUT_DATE);
        } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Here `List<OpenFindingDTO> openFindingList = openFindingRepository.getOpenFindings(Constants.INPUT_DATE);` always `null`

Execution is happening in Oracle and gives result in sql developer unit testing
The execution is successful in oracle, but the List OpenFindingDTO is null even though there is data in the table.

```
PROCEDURE OPEN_CODE_FINDINGS ( INPUT_DATE IN VARCHAR2, C_OUTPUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

Can someone help to get `OUT SYS_REFCURSOR` into `List` ?

Comment: I would change the type parameter to Class.class or ResultSet.class instead of void.class. Not sure about it, but worth trying.

Comment: @Mar-Z Below exception when I use ResultSet.class

`org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure com.bosch.rt.report.dto.OpenFindingDTO]`

Comment: Very good. Now you need only to get the list from the returned resultSet with a simple loop. Using next and get methods of resultSet.

Comment: @Mar-Z Thanks Do you have any example code ?

Comment: Please check the answer, test it and give feedback. I'm not able to test it at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBC will return a ResultSet from the stored procedure. This should be used in configuration instead of void.class. Like this:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "getOpenFindings",
  procedureName = "OPEN_CODE_FINDINGS",
  parameters = {
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = 
      ParameterMode.IN, name = "INPUT_DATE", type = String.class),
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode =
      ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "C_OUTPUT", type = ResultSet.class)
})})
```

Instead of using the JPA repository the ResultSet can be converted to the list in the service class. Like this:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = 
  entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getOpenFindings");
query.setParameter("INPUT_DATE", Constants.INPUT_DATE);
List<OpenFindingDTO> openFindingList = query.getResultList();
```

(Disclaimer: not yet tested)

Comment: `query.execute();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<OpenFindingDTO> openFindingList = query.getResultList();`
After making few correction, it works. Thanks @Mar-Z